# discord.js bot won't leave voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried almost everything to make my bot leave from the voice channel, but the bot won't leave it.
Source code:

```
Discord.VoiceConnection.disconnect();
```

This is the current code, but I have used

```
message.member.voice.channel.disconnect()
message.member.voice.channel.leave()
message.member.voiceChannel.disconnect()
message.member.voiceConnection.leave()
message.member.voiceChannel.leave()
...etc.
```

The reason I use VoiceConnection.disconnect() is
my older function
`connection.disconnect();` works and the bot leaves.
I tracked where `connection` came from and the result was from [VoiceConnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYfRm.png) and from there 
 I tried using `Discord.VoiceConnection`. But still the bot doesn't wan't do leave. I am currently using v12. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the normal discord.js package for voice

```
message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave()
```

should work. Here are you looking for the voice channel where the bot is currently in and you leave it.

If you are using the @discordjs/voice package for voice you should use

```
const voice = require('@discordjs/voice');
voice.getVoiceConnection(`guild_id`).disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
message.guild.me.voice.channel.leave();
```

message.guild.me is the Bot's Member Object in this guild, and so you get the channel and can leave it.